# Spark Total Memory Allocation

Tags: apache-spark

I have config defined as:

```
 --driver-memory 60g \
 --executor-memory 2g \
 --executor-cores 5 \
 --num-executors 140 \
```

When I execute the job based on this setup, the total memory appears as 1188 GB (1216512 MB). 
Can anyone please explain how the mentioned setup returned this allocated memory?

Comment: Are there any other jobs running around n your cluster

Comment: no. No other jobs were running.